# Bash - pass argument from array

Tags: bash

I am using bash to call tool written in java (gatk) and I need to pass multiple arguments from array as input arguments. I tried it this way, but it seems not working. Could you please help me, how to solve it?

Code:

```
java $GATK \
    -T GenotypeGVCFs  \
    -R $ref \
    -o output.vcf \
    for foo in array
    do
        --variant  $foo \
    done
```

What i want to be called:

```
java $GATK \
    -T GenotypeGVCFs  \
    -R $ref \
    -o output.vcf \
    for foo in array
    do
        --variant  file1 \
        --variant  file2 \
        --variant  file3 ...etc
    done
```

edit: sorry for misunderstandings

```
array=("file1","file2","file3"...)
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the contents of array? Where do you get file 1,2,3?

Comment: You can't just throw a `for` inside another command. It doesn't evaluate to an expression. You get an actual `for foo in array do...` in your command line.

Comment: edited - array=("file1","file2","file3"...)
@RealSkeptic - yea I know this doesnt work, so I am looking for solution how to pass into command multiple arguments from array :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that what you actually want is that if `array` contains `a b c`, to have the command

```
java $GATK \
    -T GenotypeGVCFs  \
    -R $ref \
    -o output.vcf \
    --variant a --variant b --variant c
```

If that is so, you can prepare a second array:

```
array=("file 1" "file 2" "file 3")
declare -a fullarray
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    fullarray+=( --variant "$i" )
done
```

And then

```
java $GATK \
    -T GenotypeGVCFs  \
    -R $ref \
    -o output.vcf \
    "${fullarray[@]}"
```

This will also make sure that if any of the names in `array` contains a space, it will still be passed as a proper parameter and not split into two (assuming that you didn't mess it up when you added it to the `array`).

Comment: quoting fullarray like that will pass "--variant a" as a single argument instead of as "--variant" and "a" separately, which will probably not work as intended

Comment: @wich Why do you think that? It expands each parameter in the array as a separate word.

Comment: Ah indeed, my mistake, I thought you were changing the strings, not the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

With echo and $():

```
array=(file1 file2 file3)
java $GATK \
    -T GenotypeGVCFs  \
    -R $ref \
    -o output.vcf \
    $(for foo in ${array[*]}
    do
        echo -n " --variant  $foo"
    done)
```

Comment: No; this negates any advantage using an array in the first place would provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following:

```
java $GATK \
    -T GenotypeGVCFs  \
    -R $ref \
    -o output.vcf \
    ${array[*]/#/ --variant }
```

Comment: What about possible spaces in the file names?

Comment: @RealSkeptic OP didn't bother about spaces so I didn't either

Answer (score 0):

@RealSkeptic's answer is the best. I'd write, for readability:

```
array=( "file 1" "file 2" "file 3" )
args=(
    "$GATK"
    -T GenotypeGVCFs 
    -R "$ref"
    -o output.vcf
)
for foo in "${array[@]}"; do args+=( --variant "$foo" ); done

java "${args[@]}"
```